# Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/classCallCheck' from Material-Ui

Tags: node.js, babeljs, material-ui, node-modules

I am making a node application which makes use of mostly material-ui for the ui-interface,just yesterday I ran an npm install and tried running my code after using `npm start MyApp` but I got this error below.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/classCallCheck' in 'C:\Web Applications Course\MyApp\myApp\node_modules\material-ui\node_modules\react-event-listener\dist'
```

I have done series of research on github and this platform also and most of the solutions I got were:

1. npm install react-event-listener@0.5.3
2. npm install -save babel-runtime
3. Reinstall babel-loader. rm -rf node_modules && npm install to get the latest version of babel
4. Lots more solutions i have encountered

Although none of them worked, I have invested over 20 hours on this error, please any help would be appreciated.

This is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "talk",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "overlayscrollbars": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-event-listener": "^0.5.3",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try running it on a different browser. Looks like a cross browser issue.